# Nonlinear Differential Equation with Log

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would one go about solving a higher order ODE that is non linear that is equal to a natural log? Is the Undetermined Coefficients method possible or must Variation of Parameters be used? For example, this:
$$y''=ln(y)$$
Thanks so much!

Comment: Undetermined coefficients and variation of parameters are for linear ODEs. If (and that is a big if) it is possible to get a nice analytic solution to nonlinear ODEs, finding that solution usually involves a much more clever solution.

Comment: Would you by any chance be able to elaborate on what that much more clever analysis would be? Would it possibly be a  Frobenius or some other Series solution method?

Comment: To study the differential equation $y''=f(y)$, note that $2y''y'=2f(y)y'$ hence every solution solves $(y')^2=2F(y)$, where $F$ is a primitive of $f$. Then $F(y)^{-1/2}y'=\pm2$ hence $$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{F(z)}}=\pm2t\qquad F(z)=\int f(z)dz.$$

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$w = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dw}\frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dw} y''$

$y'' = w \frac{dw}{dy}$

$w \frac{dw}{dy} = \ln(y)$

Solve this diff eq.,  then substitute back again for w. And, solve the next diff eq.